# Change figure view in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there some way of using the `surf()` style data format to create a heat map?

I have a bunch of scattered data of the form `z=f(x,y)` (so I used `TriScatteredInterp` to make it work with `meshgrid`) and I'd like to visualize `z` with a heat map. `surf` already does something similar to what I want, except you have to manually rotate the graph so the view is top down looking at the XY plane.

Basically, I'd like something similar to this: 
[image: Heat maps]

But surf gives you this by default:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the answers here already show how to do this with surf, rendering the 3d surface feels a little like overkill...

[`pcolor`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) creates the required images directly

(with slightly better results -surf has a gap next to the axes)

### code

```
figure(1)
pcolor(peaks)

figure(2)
surf(peaks)
view(2)
```

### results

---

`pcolor`
[image: pcolor Result]

---

`surf`
[image: surf Result]

Comment: Wow `pcolor`.  Didn't know about that function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Ben's answer, you can use the `view` command.  `view` allows you to rotate your plot to whatever camera angle you wish.

In general, you call the command like so:

```
view(AZ, EL);
```

`AZ` is the azimuth or horizontal rotation, while `EL` is the vertical elevation.  These are both in degrees.

In your case, once you plot your `surf` plot, use `view(0, 90);` before you go to the next `subplot`.  `view(0, 90);` is the default 2-D view, and this looks directly overhead.

---

By doing this, you avoid having to rotate your plot manually, then using `campos` to determine what the camera position is at given your plot.  `view(0, 90);` should give you what you need.

## Sidenote

Doing `view(2);` also gives you the default 2D view, which is equal to `view(0, 90);` as we talked about.  By doing `view(3);`, this gives you the default 3D view as seen in your plots.  FWIW, the default azimuth and elevation for a 3D plot is `AZ = -37.5, EL = 30`, in degrees of course.

Answer (score 5):

Rotate the view to what you want. Then type `campos` in the terminal. This shows you the camera position. You can then use `campos( your_desired )` to set the camera position for future plots.

For example, the `x, y` view is usually:

```
campos([4.0000    2.5000   86.6025])
```